Mario Bunge on Bayesianism
I was reading Bunge's book "Chasing reality" (pg 116-117) and I came across the following text:

To appreciate the enormity of the Bayesian attempted
counter-revolution, consider, for instance, the relation between the
HIV virus and AIDS. It is well known that, whereas those who have this
disease test HIV-positive, the con- verse is not true: some
individuals have lived with the virus for a decade or more without
developing AIDS. Suppose then that a given individual has contracted that virus, and that we
wish to ascertain the probability that he also has, or will soon
develop, AIDS.


Presumably, a Bayesian would set Pr(AIDS / HIV) =
Pr(HIV / AIDS) Pr(AIDS) / Pr(HIV). Further, since the individual in
question has tested HIV-positive, our Bayesian is likely to set
Pr(HIV)
= 1. And, since it is known that whoever has AIDS also has the HIV virus, Pr(HIV / AIDS) = 1. Thus, Bayes’s formula simplifies to Pr(AIDS
/ HIV) = Pr(AIDS). However, this is known to be false: in fact, HIV is
necessary but not sufficient to develop AIDS. So, if AIDS researchers
were to adopt Bayesianism, they would not try to discover the causes
that, jointly with HIV infection, lead to AIDS.

As a person with experience in statistics, I believe 99% of statisticians would never set P(HIV) to 1 just because the person has it. The probability refers to the entire population not to P(HIV/HIV) (which is obviously 1). How would you interpret Bunge's text here? Am I missing something?

You are right. It is ironic that before the example Bunge writes "any ideas can have bad consequences if handled incompetently" and then proceeds to do just that. His 'calculation' is analyzed by Klement, p. 10 :"The paradox only arises because Bunge is wrong in two assumptions:
First, that a positive test result is “true”, so that P(HIV) = 1, and second that the test has perfect sensitivity, so that P(HIV|AIDS) = 1... Regarding Bunge’s first assumption, he mistakenly identifies “knowing or observing the data” with “the probability of the data”."

@Conifold Thx for the source. Very insightful!

@Conifold is there a relevant difference for this question between being an statistician and being a bayesian? I've somehow always interpreted those terms differently, understanding the second as a philosophical tendency to interpret what statistics reveals about knowledge. What are your thoughts on this?

P(AIDS | HIV) = P(AIDS) However, this is known to be false: in fact,  means HIV is necessary but not sufficient to develop AIDS. (Given, as in the quote in the question, that the sample has P(HIV)=1.)
There's nothing else to say. The author simply does not understand the statistics.

Just before I accept the answer, please confirm that the first sentence is sarcasm. I want to make sure it's clear for other readers as well. I have mad respect for him but he also published the book at the end of his life so I suppose one can be lenient on him.

I'll change the wording to be less confrontational.

I passed freshman statistics, but that was over a decade ago and I was never confident in my understanding. But, isn't that false? P(AIDS|HIV) =P(AIDS) means that the probability of AIDS is unchanged by knowing the person has HIV. This is true if P(HIV) is 1 within the population, or if HIV and AIDS are uncorrelated. I can't see it meaning necessary-but-not-sufficient. By analogy, for a D6 P(6|Even) = 1/3 != P(6), for a simple necessary-but-not-sufficient case

@TheDarkCanuck The sample in the quote has P(HIV)=1. I'll mention that in the answer to avoid confusion so that the answer is self-contained.
